# Service does not have a Binding with the None Message Version

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Ok. So I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I have tried a few things. There's even a few posts here about this very same problem, but seems like I just cannot get this right.

I have a website that is running rest services, and everything is working fine when I use normal "http".

So today I was like "...hey, let's enable SSL, because we will have to run the website with SSL anyways later on...", and this is what I did:
- Clicked on the project, and pressed F4 (open properties) and ->

[image]

Great. When I run the wesbite:

[image]

And this is what my serviceModel looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!--<services>
      <service name="Stolen.Service">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="Stolen.IService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>-->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Stolen.Service">
        <endpoint address="rest"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="RestfulBehavior"
                  contract="Stolen.IService"/>
        <!--<endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="RestfulBehavior"
                  contract="Stolen.IService"/>-->
        <!--<endpoint address="mex"
                   binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                   contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
        <!--<endpoint address="soap" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="SOAPBehavior"
                  contract="Stolen.IService" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestfulBehavior">
          <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <!--<behavior name="SOAPBehavior">

        </behavior>-->
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And one of the services that I have:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "IncrementWebsiteVisitCount",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string IncrementWebsiteVisitCount();
```

Some posts have suggested that the

```
<webHttp/>
```

be removed. Some also suggested that this is because I have configured a single endpointBehavior for both SOAP and REST endpoints. I dunno, this one gets me!

Can anyone perhaps help me out? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up changing a few things.
But only in the web config file.
My serviceModel now looks like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <!-- As far as I know, webHttpBinding means it is a REST service -->
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Stolen.Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/Service.svc/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="web"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="Stolen.IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

With this, everything is working fine for me now, with SSL.